# How to prevent users to write to database in Neo4j Browser?

Tags: neo4j

According to this link:

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/native-roles/

It seems I can create user based on specific roles so that some users can only read the database, not write. However, the documentation shows it's for enterprise version. Is that true?

How to provide read-only access in Neo4j Browser of the community version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [community edition's user management](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/reference/user-management-community-edition/) capabilities are very limited. Although the community edition allows you to create multiple users, they will all have full `admin` privileges.